# When zooming, circle gets 'dragged' from original position

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using mapbox.js and map.css to create a map with a simple circle drawn on it, and nothing else. ([working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfn6adr7/)) On the example that I did without angular, the zoom works as it should (meaning, it stays on the same position when zooming).
When I integrated with the example and I zoom, the circle gets dragged slightly to the top left when zooming out and to the bottom right when I zoom in, in the end returning to the original position when the zoom stops. 
On the angular project I'm using require to load the scripts to the page and the view that has the map is not the first one that is loaded. I am not using a directive for leaflet, just using the files. The code is exactly the same from the example to the angular project, the only difference is that I am not using a script tag in the html file as I was in the example (since the code has been moved to the controller).

I wanted the behaviour to be the same as it was in the example but at this stage I don't know what might be causing it besides the fact that is not the view that is first being loaded.

Here's the view code:

```
<div id="leafletMap" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Here's the code in my controller:

```
/* globals L, $ */
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @ngdoc function
     * @name rmsPortalApp.controller:ViewMapCtrl
     * @description
     * # ViewMapCtrl
     * Controller of the rmsPortalApp
     */
    angular.module('rmsPortalApp.controllers.ViewMapCtrl', [])
        .controller('ViewMapCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
            var ownerCircleLayer;

                L.Map = L.Map.extend({
                    openPopup: function (popup) {
                        //        this.closePopup();  // just comment this
                        this._popup = popup;

                        return this.addLayer(popup).fire('popupopen', {
                            popup: this._popup
                        });
                    }
                });

                var map = L.map('leafletMap', {
                    touchZoom: true,
                    dragging: true
                }).setView([39.678, -8.229], 6);

                /* Initialize the SVG layer */
                //map._initPathRoot();

                /* SVG from the map object */
                //var svg = d3.select("#map").select("svg");

                var southWest = [85.05, -180.01];
                var northEast = [-85.06, 180.05];

                var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

                map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

                L.tileLayer('http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/bmpgp.010fd6a5/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYm1wZ3AiLCJhIjoiOWY4NGYwN2VjZDg0MGI1ZjdmMWI3ZjdlNGNmY2NmNmQifQ.FZ5cr4mO3iDKVkx9zz4Nkg', {
                    attribution: '© Powered By <a href="http://www.cgi.com">CGI</a>',
                    minZoom: 3,
                    maxZoom: 18,
                    id: 'bmpgp.010fd6a5',
                    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYm1wZ3AiLCJhIjoiOWY4NGYwN2VjZDg0MGI1ZjdmMWI3ZjdlNGNmY2NmNmQifQ.FZ5cr4mO3iDKVkx9zz4Nkg'
                }).addTo(map);

                setOwnerCircle()

                function setOwnerCircle() {
                    ownerCircleLayer = new L.layerGroup();

                    var ownerCircle = L.circle([39, -8], 3000, {
                        color: 'red',
                        opacity: 1,
                        weigth: 1,
                        fillOpacity: 0.0,
                        className: 'leaflet-zoom-animated'
                    });

                ownerCircleLayer.addLayer(ownerCircle);

                var circleBounds = ownerCircle.getBounds();

                // Image popup
                var endLat = circleBounds.getCenter().lat - 0.10000;
                var endLon = circleBounds.getEast();

                map.addLayer(ownerCircleLayer);

                addedOwnerCircle = true;
            }
        })
});
```

EDIT: 
I have tried putting it in the first view that is being loaded, it still happens.

Comment: Please post your finding as an answer instead of editing the question

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason why it was happening:
When double checking the actual mapbox.js and mapbox.css I noticed that my css was wrong, upon replacing it with the right mapbox.css it stopped doing the dragging. Thank you for the help regardless.